# MSK vs SQS + SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, microservices, messaging, aws-msk

I am deciding if I should use MSK (managed kafka from AWS) or a combination of SQS + SNS to achieve a pub sub model?

**Background**

Currently, we have a micro service architecture but we don't use any messaging service and only use REST apis (dont ask why - related to some 3rd party vendors who designed the architecture). Now, I want to revamp it and start using messaging for communication between micro-services.

Initially, the plan is to start publishing entity events for any other micro service to consume - these events will also be stored in data lake in S3 which will also serve as a base for starting data team.

Later, I want to move certain features from REST to async communication.

Anyway, the main question I have is - should I decide to go with MSK or should I use SQS + SNS for the same? ( I already understand the basic concepts but wanted to understand from fellow community if there are some other pros and cons)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Congrats for not having your question insta-closed because it's "opinion-based". I profited from the question and the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MSK VS SQS+SNS is not really 1:1 comparison. The choice depends on various use cases. Please find out some of specific difference between two

1. Scalability ->
   MSK has better scalability option because of inherent design of partitions that allow parallelism and ordering of message.
   SNS has limitation of 300 publish/Second, to achieve same performance as MSK, there need to have higher number of SNS topic for same purpose.

Example : Topic: Order Service
in MSK -> one topic+ 10 Partitions
SNS     -> 10 topics

if client/message producer use 10 SNS topic for same purpose, then client needs to have information of all 10 SNS topic and distribution of message.
In MSK, it's pretty straightforward, key needs to send in message and kafka will allocate the partition based on Key value.

2. Administration/Operation ->
   SNS+SQS setup is much simpler compare to MSK.
   Operational challenge is much more with MSK( even this is managed service). MSK needs more in depth skills to use optimally.
3. SNS +SQS VS SQS -> I believe you have multiple subscription(fanout) for same message thats why you have refer SNS +SQS.
   If you have One Subscription for one message, then only SQS is also sufficient.
4. Replay of message -> MSK can be use for replaying the already processed message.
   It will be tricky for SQS, though can be achieve by having duplicate queue so that can be use for replay.